# EC2 Instances - Are they Just Containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

I'm so confused.

I created an EC2 Instance.  So this isn't a "Host"?  It's a container instance?  I'm confused then if that's the case.  Then what's the host for the images or how does this work?  I pulled an image from docker hub to it, pushed the image to the AWS registry, and then now what?  I want to run a container to run my app...so this "EC2 Instance" IS the container image?  And there is no real "Host" virtual server here?

So looking at the way Docker works, what's the Host and what's the container with EC2?  Are the "EC2 Instances" the containers in the below diagram I got from a book about docker?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EC2 instance is a virtual machine running on a physical host. If you want to run a container, make sure docker is installed on your instance, and run your docker commands.

Docker host is your EC2 instance.

Comment: then what are "Container Instances" in AWS?  Because the way they talk about Container Instances is they say create an instance from your EC2 control panel and those are virtual servers in themselves!  How can a container be a separate virtual server?  I thought the EC2 instance was the HOST where I install docker on and then somehow create docker containers off an image I store in my AWS Repo? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html.  I'm mixed up on either translating AWS's terminology or it's blurring the lines for me here

Comment: I think you are confusing with EC2 container service: https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/

Comment: I've installed docker on my Ec2 Instance and now I've got to a point where as I was ssh'd into my running EC2 virtual instance, from the command-line from within my running instance, I used the AWS CLI and added an image I pulled from docker hub into my EC2 Container registry.  Now I want to launch a container, so I'm confused at this point because it says to create a new Instance.  I'm already in an instance!

Comment: The terminology AWS has chosen for their docker offering is unfortunately confusing. When they say "instance", it always refers to one virtual machine. Every virtual machine that runs docker is a docker host. A container image is the dormant version of a running docker container.

Comment: @code_monk then what's a "container instance" ? errr

Comment: @code_monk if a "container instance" is really my "Host"...then how do I create a docker container to run my app and have the host run that container?

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding how docker works..or I am.  But I thought it'd work like this:  I have an aws virtual server which is my "Host".  I run docker on it.  I'm able to then launch containers off it and essentially run my blog off a container running on the host.

Comment: A container instance is the name for one host in a swarm, in Amazon's ECS service. You don't need ECS to run docker. A regular instance will do. Let's take this into chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76919/docker

Comment: And there's also a problem in that when you go to create an EC2 instance, it asks for an image to use.  Well I don't have one, I'm using the wizard to create the instance after I selected Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09.1 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-60b6c60a and when you go through that wizard, there is no IAM role to choose as well as no "AMI".  After the instance is created, it states an AMI ID of amzn-ami-hvm-2015.09.1.x86_64-gp2 (ami-60b6c60a) but in my AMI section of the EC2 Control panel no AMIs exist!

Comment: @PositiveGuy in AWS specifically, a container instance is intended as "an Amazon EC2 instance that is running the Amazon ECS container agent and has been registered into an Amazon ECS cluster". If you decide that you're using Podman for spinning up those containers inside EC2 instances, you will pick an AMI for your EC2 that doesn't include Docker, install Podman on it, instruct it to download your container image and spin it. You can spin multiple containers with the same container image, and they will constitute container instances of your container image. I'm years late, hope u're good now.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I've checked Amazon would't let you provision just a single container. You'll need to provision the whole EC2 instance and then start the container within it as you will do within your own desktop.

Comment: right that's what I thought I was doing, create an EC2 virtual instance (which  I thought was the "host" in that diagram that runs the daemon) and then somehow create and run container instances within it somehow...But the way they talk about containers they call them instances and when you go through the docs to create "container instances" they tell you to click Create Instance in your EC2 panel and I'm like wtf, I've already got an EC2 instance when I first went through the initial wizard prior to create an EC2 instance.  http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/

Comment: When I created the EC2 instance a week ago, I went through their create an EC2 instance wizard to guide me to create the free for one year instance deal.